# Divisor sum of totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

> Is there any closed form expression for $\displaystyle\sum_{d|n}  d\phi(d)$?

I have tried a lot but can only reduce it to $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{(k,n)}$ where $(k,n)$ is the greatest common divisor. But it cannot be simplified.

Comment: Not sure if it is useful, but $d\phi(d)=\phi(d^2)$.

Comment: Your second sum can be seen as the sum of the orders of the elements of the cyclic group of order $n$. So dividing by $n$, it is the expected order of a random element take from a cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: Like most problems in life, this can be solved with [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A057660).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sum is (weakly) multiplicative:  if $(m,n)=1$ then any divisor $d$ of $mn$ can be written uniquely as $d=d_1d_2$ where $d_1|n$ and $d_2|m$.

Therefore it suffices to compute your sum for prime powers.  We have $$\sum_{d|p^k}d\varphi(d)=\sum_{i=0}^k p^i\varphi(p^i)$$

Writing this out we get (barring arithmetic error) $$1+p(p-1)+p^3(p-1)+\dots =1+(p-1)p\left[1+p^2+\dots +p^{2(k-1)}\right]$$ $$=1+(p-1)p\frac {p^{2k}-1}{p^2-1}=1+p\frac {p^{2k}-1}{p+1}=\frac {p^{2k+1}+1}{p+1}$$