# $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(i,n)}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, gcd-and-lcm

Find the value of this series:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(i,n)}.$$

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: What is your work so far?

Comment: See very-related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517367/divisor-sum-of-totient-function

Answer (score 3):

For each divisor $d$ of $n$ there are exactly $\phi\left(\frac nd\right)$ terms in the sum whose value is $\frac nd$, so

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac n{(j,n)}=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac nd\phi\left(\frac nd\right)=\sum_{d\mid n}d\phi(d)=\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d^2)$$

Comment: Could you explain (or provide some reference) why there are exactly $\phi(n/d)$ terms in the sum with value $n/d$?

Comment: I think I got it. If the term for $1 \leq i \leq n$ has value $n/d$, then $\gcd(i, n) = d$. On the other hand, this happens iff $\gcd(i, n/d) = n/d$. Is this correct?