# Sum involving $\gcd$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

I was asked to evaluate the sum $\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$. I know that there are $\phi(n)$ integers $k < n$ such that $\gcd(n,k) = 1$ so I tried writting $\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)} = \phi(n)n + 1 + S$ where $S$ is the contribution from the terms where $k < n$ and $\gcd(n,k) > 1$.

I've also tried evaluating $\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{\text{lcm}(n,k)}{k}$ but to no avail.

I would preferably like a hint as opposed to a full solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is the cyclic group of order $n$ and $G=\langle g\rangle $,
then $ord(g^k)=\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$.

Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}
= \sum_{k = 1}^n ord(g^k)
= \sum_{d\mid n} \sum_{x \in G, ord(x)=d} d
= \sum_{d\mid n} d \phi(d)
$$

For the last sum, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517367/divisor-sum-of-totient-function).